# Popular View com JSON

Tags: json, swift

Utilizo uma library chamada [Alamofire-SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/Alamofire-SwiftyJSON) para fazer uma requisição `JSON`.

**Exemplo de chamada:**

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
         .responseSwiftyJSON({ (request, response, json, error) in
                     println(json)
                     println(error)
 })
```

Esta url é apenas um exemplo, o retorno do meu `JSON` É assim:

**Exemplo de retorno JSON:**

```
{
   "titulo1": "Silvio Santos Ipsum",
   "texto1": "Ma vai pra lá. Ma vai pra lá. Ma você, topa ou não topamm. O prêmio é em barras de ouro, que vale mais que dinheiroam. Ma vejam só, vejam só. Mah você não consegue né Moisés?",
   "url1": "http://lorempixel.com/image_output/abstract-q-g-263-221-3.jpg",
   "url2": "http://lorempixel.com/image_output/abstract-q-g-263-221-3.jpg",
   "url3": "http://lorempixel.com/image_output/abstract-q-g-263-221-3.jpg",
   "titulo2": "Patríciaaammmm... Luiz Ricardouaaammmmmm.",
   "texto2": "É namoro ou amizadeemm? Ma vale dérreaisam? Você veio da caravana de ondeammm? Ma não existem mulher feiam, existem mulher que não conhece os produtos Jequitiamm. Um, dois três, quatro, PIM, entendeuam? Patríciaaammmm... Luiz Ricardouaaammmmmm. O Raul Gil é gayam! ... Maa O Ah Ae! Ih Ih! O Raul Gil é gayamm! Mah é a porta da esperançaam."
}
```

Vou sempre seguir o Padrão:

- titulo + número
- texto + número

E as vezes :

- url + número.

Como posso popular minha view com estas informações?

Comment: Esse JSON terá somente um campo? Ou N campos? De forma geral eu sugeriria você montar uma solução utilizando uitableview e células customizadas. No momento não posto uma resposta completa pois estou sem tempo para dar todos os detalhes necessários.

Comment: @Otávio terá n campos por que será uma página de texto normal, com um campo título que terá uma fonte negritada com fonte maior é um campo texto com fonte reduzida e sem negrito e as imagens

Comment: Mas minha pergunta foi mais no sentido: Essa estrutura Titulos + Imagens se repetirá? Por exemplo `[ silvioSantos, ratinho, xuxa, faustoSilva]` ? Onde cada *celebridade* teria seus proprios títulos e imagens?

Comment: @Otávio títulos e textos se repetira agora imagens não sera em todas as telas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu concordo com a resposta do @JefersonAssis que você deveria retornar um Json em formato array.

Concordo também com o comentário do @Otávio, você deveria usar uma UITableView e um CustomCell.

Mas se você prefere usar essa sua abordagem, você teria que criar algo parecido com isto:

```
var i = 1
while true {
    i = i + 1
    if let titulo = json["titulo" + i] {
           //cria uma view dinamicamente
           var view=UIView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 200 * i, 100, 100))

           //cria os labels dinamicamente e adiciona na view
           var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 10, 200, 21))
           label.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
           label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
           label.text = titulo
           view.addSubview(label) 

           //se tem título é certo que tem texto?
           if let texto = json["texto" + i] {
               var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 20, 200, 21))
               label.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
               label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
               label.text = texto
               view.addSubview(label) 
           }
           //e assim por diante com os outros dados do array
           //adiciona a view criada na Subview principal, ou em uma view com IBOutlet que você tenha criado pelo MainStoryBoard
           self.view.addSubview(view)
   }
   else {
      //se não tem a propriedade com o número de "i", então deve sair do loop
      break
   }

}
```

Comment: segui a abordagem de criar uma tableview para o preenchimento dos campos, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101915/como-customizar-uitableview

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro você precisa corrigir o seu retorno, hoje ele esta retornando um objeto e vez de um `array` contendo vários objetos

Em vez desse retorno:

```
{
   "titulo1": "Silvio Santos Ipsum",
   "texto1": "Ma vai pra lá. Ma vai pra lá. Ma você, topa ou não topamm. O prêmio é em barras de ouro, que vale mais que dinheiroam. Ma vejam só, vejam só. Mah você não consegue né Moisés?",
   "url1": "http://lorempixel.com/image_output/abstract-q-g-263-221-3.jpg",
   "url2": "http://lorempixel.com/image_output/abstract-q-g-263-221-3.jpg",
   "url3": "http://lorempixel.com/image_output/abstract-q-g-263-221-3.jpg",
   "titulo2": "Patríciaaammmm... Luiz Ricardouaaammmmmm.",
   "texto2": "É namoro ou amizadeemm? Ma vale dérreaisam? Você veio da caravana de ondeammm? Ma não existem mulher feiam, existem mulher que não conhece os produtos Jequitiamm. Um, dois três, quatro, PIM, entendeuam? Patríciaaammmm... Luiz Ricardouaaammmmmm. O Raul Gil é gayam! ... Maa O Ah Ae! Ih Ih! O Raul Gil é gayamm! Mah é a porta da esperançaam."
}
```

Mude para algo assim:

```
[{
   "titulo": "Silvio Santos Ipsum",
   "texto": "Ma vai pra lá. Ma vai pra lá. Ma você, topa ou não topamm. O prêmio é em barras de ouro, que vale mais que dinheiroam. Ma vejam só, vejam só. Mah você não consegue né Moisés?",
   "url1": "http://lorempixel.com/image_output/abstract-q-g-263-221-3.jpg",
   "url2": "http://lorempixel.com/image_output/abstract-q-g-263-221-3.jpg",
   "url3": "http://lorempixel.com/image_output/abstract-q-g-263-221-3.jpg"
},
{
   "titulo": "Patríciaaammmm... Luiz Ricardouaaammmmmm.",
   "texto": "É namoro ou amizadeemm? Ma vale dérreaisam? Você veio da caravana de ondeammm? Ma não existem mulher feiam, existem mulher que não conhece os produtos Jequitiamm. Um, dois três, quatro, PIM, entendeuam? Patríciaaammmm... Luiz Ricardouaaammmmmm. O Raul Gil é gayam! ... Maa O Ah Ae! Ih Ih! O Raul Gil é gayamm! Mah é a porta da esperançaam."
}]
```

Para popular sua `view`, caso esteja utilizando `IBOutlet` basta chamado dessa forma:

```
if let JSON = response.result.value {
    labelTitulo?.text = JSON[0]!["titulo"]
}
```

No exemplo acima coloquei sempre pegando índice 0 do `array`, mas você pode fazer o looping e adequar a sua necessidade

Comment: Jeferson, o retorno deverá ser aquele, pois já e o utilizado em uma aplicação Android. ele retorna um JSON válido. só irá mudar a manipulação dele. e no seu  JSON[0]!["titulo1"] deveria ficar apenas  JSON[0]!["titulo"] se fosse o caso. e eu não criei nenhum IBOutlet, estava pensando em colocar tudo programaticamente por que eu não sei o tamanho que os textos poderam vir...

Comment: +1  esta é uma área fraca aqui, sua ajuda é muito bem vinda.

Comment: Entendi, mas aconselho a mudar nos dois, você não tem nenhum referencia de quantos objetos ele retornou. eu utilizo sempre com auto layout, o label redimensiona sozinho independente do tamanho do texto que vem (Corrigi o titulo1 na resposta, valeu :) )